# How to properly dispose / release PowerPoint.DocumentWindow

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, powerpoint

**Question :** how to dispose child Excel window that was created by parent PPT process?

1. I copy chart from Excel to Power Point 2013
2. then I click with right mouse button on this chart and choose "Edit Data"
3. compact popup Excel window appears with a source data for this chart
4. I close this window and cannot open it again because seems that handle of this window was not properly released

Here is the code used to update PPT Chart if some data in Excel window changes.

```
protected void UpdateSlide()
{
    using (PresentationWrapper presentation = ParentSlide.Parent)
    using (DocumentWindowWrapper window = presentation.Windows[0]) // !!! here is the place where Com oject is maintained but needs to be released
    {
        window.Activate();
    }
}
```

Here is wrapper that does not release Com object.

```
public class DocumentWindowWrapper : ComWrapper<ppt.DocumentWindow>, IWindow
{
    DocumentWindowWrapper wrapper;

    public static DocumentWindowWrapper CreateWrapper(ppt.DocumentWindow wrappedObject)
        wrapper = new DocumentWindowWrapper(wrappedObject);
        return wrapper;
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(...); // !!! what should I put here to release this window?
        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This is the window I am talking about.

[image]

Comment: As Yegor hints, `presentation.Windows[0]` creates two .NET wrappers (`Windows` and `DocumentWindow`) and only one is released. Maybe that's your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying COM object (**wrappedObject**) should be released using the ReleaseComObject method.

Answer (score 0):

The code should look like:

To start working with sheet:

```
Worksheets sheets = excelApp.Worksheets; 
Worksheet sheet = sheets.Open(...);
```

and then to release (they are always released in reverse order of creation):

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheets);
```